# Compare boolean values in PostgreSQL 9.3 json objects

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Is there any other way to match a boolean value from a PostgreSQL (**version 9.3**) json object without converting it to string?

What I mean is:
The table contains the following object in its jsoncolumn column:

```
'{"path":"mypath", "exists": true}'
```

the following query fetches the record (note that the `exists` value is fetched as text with `->>`):

```
select * from thetable where jsoncolumn ->> 'exists' = 'true';
```

and this one doesn't:

```
select * from thetable where jsoncolumn -> 'exists' = true;
```

I wonder if there is a more appropriate way to do a boolean comparison?

Comment: Did you try: `(jsoncolumn -> 'exists')::boolean = true`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I have. it didn't work either.

Answer (score 4):

Here're all the valid combinations to validate json(b) boolean:

```
-- This works only with jsonb, not with json because in Postgres json type is just a string.
SELECT $${ "exists": true }$$::jsonb -> 'exists' = 'true';
-[ RECORD 1 ]
?column? | t

-- All the following works with regular json as well with jsonb:
SELECT ( $${ "exists": true }$$::json ->> 'exists' )::boolean;
-[ RECORD 1 ]
bool | t

SELECT ( $${ "exists": true }$$::json ->> 'exists' )::boolean IS TRUE;
-[ RECORD 1 ]
?column? | t

SELECT ( $${ "exists": true }$$::json ->> 'exists' )::boolean = TRUE;
-[ RECORD 1 ]
?column? | t
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value as text then cast to boolean:

```
select pg_typeof((j ->> 'exists')::boolean)
from (values ('{"path":"mypath", "exists": true}'::json)) v(j)
;
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 boolean
```

[Valid boolean literals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-boolean.html#DATATYPE-BOOLEAN-TABLE)

Comment: my question is how to query if the value is true rather than check if it is a boolean. sorry if it was unclear from my question.

Comment: That was to show how to get a boolean and not a json. You can just use it as intended.

Comment: This doesn't work. You can't tell the difference between `{"exists": "true"}` and `{"exists": true}` using this method.